# Mongo Db Query to sort by the field and also aggregate the results which do not have that field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

query should be sorted by 'lastUsedTimestamp' in ASC. If these entities lastUsedTimestamp is null or expired or do not have the field, we just remove them from the collection with defined limit.

I have them written like below but it is giving null

```
    Criteria fieldsCriteria1 = Criteria.where("lastAccessTimestamp").lte(date);  
    Criteria fieldsCriteria2 = Criteria.where("lastAccessTimestamp").exists(false);

    Query query2 = new Query();
    query2.limit(3);  
    query2.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC,"lastAccessTimestamp")); // to set in ASC order
    query2.addCriteria(fieldsCriteria1);  // to set the expired time
    If i have only these above criteria added it works fine, the problem occurs when i add the below criteria
    query2.addCriteria(fieldsCriteria2);  // to get if the lastAccessTimestamp field is empty
```

I am new to Mongo Db, also I am not sure which is the best way to fulfill the above query.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you do not want to include those documents where `lastAccessTimestamp` is null or does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

I had figured out the solution, the below query worked for me.

```
var fieldsCriteria = new Criteria()
.orOperator(Criteria.where(LAST_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP).lt(date)
,Criteria.where(LAST_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP).exists(false)
);
var query = new Query();
query.limit(limit);
query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, LAST_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP));
query.addCriteria(fieldsCriteria);
List<Document> list=mongoTemplate.find(query,Document.class,collectionName);
```